# What is the simplest way to send GPS data to a server? (2017)

Tags: android, gps

I'm coming back to Android programming after a 2-3 year break.  Previously I would use `HttpClient` to do something like:

```
    List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User_ID", userID));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude", lat));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", lon));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GPS_Accuracy", acc));       

    try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://url/add_post_to_table.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

This method would be setup with an AlarmManager and BroadcastReciever to update periodically and the POST would be processed by a Php script that stores it in an SQL table.

After coming back to Android, there seem to be too many options for replacing this functionality. **To be clear, the functionality I am trying to replace is: Updating an SQL table with user GPS data periodically.** There are many ways to do this, but all of the methods seem overly complex for sending an post on location change.

It seems there are 4 popular options

1. Async task with [httpURLconnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).
2. Retrofithttp:  square.github.io/retrofit/
3. Volleyhttps:  developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html
4. Robospice:  github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide

*sorry for the bad links, github limits the ammount of links you can post with <10 points*

Perhaps it's just me, but #1 seems the simplest. However, most people on the internet (including stackoverflow) seem to swear by #2-4. The problem I am running into is that each of these solutions (especially #2-4) are fairly deep to learn and provide infinitely more features than I care to learn. That being said, **What is the *simplest* way to update a remote SQL table with user GPS data in July of 2017?**

Answer (score 0):

You found Volley/ Retrofit complex, so here is AsyncTask sample that you can follow

```
private class AsyncLocationUpload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //DO something
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String stgUrl = params[0];
            String data = params[1]; 

    try {
        URL url = new URL(stgUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlconnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlconnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlconnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlconnection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlconnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
        responseCode = urlconnection.getResponseCode(); //check if your request was successful

        if (responseCode != 200) {
            //Failed
        } else {
            //Success
            InputStream inputStream = urlconnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String resultString;
            while ((resultString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    resultBuffer.append(resultString);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return resultBuffer.toString();
}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //Do Something
            }

    }
```

Create JsonObject of the parameter you want to send

```
JSONObject locationParameter = new JSONObject();
locationParameter.put("User_ID", userID);
locationParameter.put("Latitude", lat);
locationParameter.put("Longitude", lon);
locationParameter.put("GPS_Accuracy", acc);

String url="";
new AsyncLocationUpload(this).execute(url,String.valueOf(locationParameter));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Subhechhu,

For anyone who may stumble across this in the future, here is what I ended up doing:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public void asyncPost() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("user_ID", user_ID);
    params.put("gps_acquire_time", gpsAquireTime);
    params.put("lat", lat);
    params.put("lon", lon);
    params.put("acc", acc);
    client.post("http://website.com/phpscript.php", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res) {
                    Log.e(TAG, res);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, res);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

It uses the [Loopj AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library and makes the whole process really simple.  This was then wrapped in a service to so it can continue to send updates in the background and after the app is closed.